# How can I set a remote computer as the target for MSSQL Server 2008 R2's Copy Database task?

Tags: sql-server, database, task

The target database is located on a LAN with a local IP. The local IPs are distributed by my modem's DHCP server and is something like 192.168.1.xxx. I've already redirected port 1433 to the machine which holds the sql server (192.168.1.xxx) and I can reach to it with a SQL Management Studio connection, using my WAN IP from the source machine. However, when I write my WAN IP as the Copy Database task's target, it returns an error which indicates that connection cannot be established.

Might I be missing the writing convention for the target? I tried the following (my WAN IP is 78.187.xxx.xxx and my target MSSQL Server's name is EXP32):

```
78.187.xxx.xxx
78.187.xxx.xxx\EXP32
\\78.187.xxx.xxx
\\78.187.xxx.xxx\EXP32
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GO TO

```
-> SQL server configuration manager
-> On network configuration -> protocol for mssqlserver -> enable except VIA
-> go to component services and on services restart sqlserver and express if you have
```

Comment: Thank you for your promptness. However, the source DB must run at all times. Isn't there another way to do this without restarting the service? --Sorry, I just checked and noticed that under Protocols for MSSQLSERVER, all items are already enabled except VIA.